# [Ckan]. Can't make Javascript work in CKAN

Tags: javascript, ckan, fanstatic

I'm trying to follow the example reported here: [Ckan theming - Javascript](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/theming/javascript.html) in order to understand how I can add some javascript to my pages. Unfortunately, I can't make the example work. 
I have a theme called *theme*, and I'd like to modify that one. So in my ckanext-theme/ckanext/theme/fanstatic/ folder, I add the *theme_popover.js* file, as per the example (I changed all the file names accordingly). I also put in ckanext-theme/ckanext/theme/templates/snippets/ the *package_item.html* defined as shown in the example (and changed to match the file names I got).

When I reload my /dataset/ page, all I got is an "internal server error". I searched the logs for further explanation, and here the error I got in my ckan_default.error.log file:

> Blockquote 
>   [Tue May 30 10:43:17.351659 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 24241:tid 140295054444288] [remote 172.17.0.1:31237] Error - : invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>   [Tue May 30 10:43:17.545679 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 24241:tid 140295054444288] [remote 172.17.0.1:31237] URL: http://localhost:10080/dataset

I can't quite grasp what it means and what should I fix to make it work.
Can somebody help me? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please supply the traceback too. For more info see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074462/ckan-error-server-error-500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it was my fault. I had not added the         toolkit.add_resource('fanstatic', 'theme') line to my plugin file.
I added that and everything works fine now!