# When creating a ckan.dump does it store the actual files uploaded in each dataset?

Tags: ckan

I am trying to import a `ckan.dump`(version 2.5.2) into another build of `ckan` 2.7.2 but I am unable to preview or download the files stored in each dataset. However,I can see the list of datasets and organisations.

This is the error when trying to download:

```
 ⇝ AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace that is associated with the error message. For more details see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44074463/1512326

Comment: When you added the datasets to CKAN originally, did you upload each data file or did you supply a link to them where they were located elsewhere on the internet?

Comment: Most of the data is supplied via  a link to them elsewhere on the internet, I realised that the url is wrong in the new ckan build that I have. Is there a way to change them without doing each one manually.